# Can't display a Refinable String in my Item Template

Tags: 2013, search, display-template, item

I have created an item template, which is a copy of the 'Word Item' template. Within the libraries I'm searching against, I have a Yes/No field called 'privatedoc' which I have mapped to the 'RefinableString10' managed property.

Using the SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool, I have verified that the 'RefinableString10' managed property is returning values of 'True' and 'False' where appropriate.

I have included the RefinableString property in my ManagedPropertyMapping as so:

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'RefinableString10':'RefinableString10','Title':'Title','Path':'Path','Description':'Description','EditorOWSUSER':'EditorOWSUSER','LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime','CollapsingStatus':'CollapsingStatus','DocId':'DocId','HitHighlightedSummary':'HitHighlightedSummary','HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties','FileExtension':'FileExtension','ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime','ParentLink':'ParentLink','FileType':'FileType','IsContainer':'IsContainer','SecondaryFileExtension':'SecondaryFileExtension','DisplayAuthor':'DisplayAuthor','ServerRedirectedURL':'ServerRedirectedURL','SectionNames':'SectionNames','SectionIndexes':'SectionIndexes','ServerRedirectedEmbedURL':'ServerRedirectedEmbedURL','ServerRedirectedPreviewURL':'ServerRedirectedPreviewURL','privatedocOWSBOOL':'privatedocOWSBOOL'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

And called the value of the property here:

```
<div>Confidential Flag = _#= ctx.currentItem_RefinableString10 =#_ <br></div>
```

However, the RefinableString10 value is not displaying. I have tried rebuilding the index on the libraries, and if I call a different property ('Title' for instance) it displays fine.

Am I missing something minor? I just can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar example in the same type of Display template and it works fine.

You can try this instead:

```
Confidential Flag = _#= ctx.currentItem.RefinableString10 =#_
```